# Extracting values from a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

So I'm working on taking a txt file and converting it into a csv data table.

I have managed to convert the data into a csv file and put it into a table, but I have a problem with extracting the numbers. In the data table that I made, it's giving me text as well as the value (intensity = 12345).

How do I only put the numerical values into the table?

I tried using regular expressions, but I couldn't get it to work. I would also like to delete all the lines that contain saturated, fragmented and merged. I initially created a code that would delete every uneven line, but this is a code that will be used for several files, so the odd lines in other files might have different data in them. How would I go about doing that?

This is the code that I currently have, plus a picture of what the output looks like.

```py
import pandas as pd
  
parameters = pd.read_csv("ScanHeader1.txt", header=None)
  
parameters.columns = ['Packet Number', 'Intensity','Mass/Position']
  
parameters.to_csv('ScanHeader1.csv', index=None)

df = pd.read_csv('ScanHeader1.csv')

print(df)
```

[image: snippet code screenshoot]

I would really appreciate some tips or pointers on how I can do this. Thanks :)

Comment: can you add a small example with a few lines from `ScanHeader1.txt` and your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
def fun_eq(x):
    x = x.split(' = ')
    return x[1]

def fun_hash(x):
    x = x.split(' # ')
    return x[1]

df = df.iloc[::2]
df['Intensity'] = df['Intensity'].apply(fun_eq)
df['Mass/Position'] = df['Mass/Position'].apply(fun_eq)
df['Packet Number'] = df['Packet Number'].apply(fun_hash)
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! This worked perfectly :)) I really appreciate that you took the time to help me, thank you!

Comment: you can appreciate me by thumbs up the answer section, thank you!